# Triggering flashing light from multiple sources

Tags: led, diodes, relay

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this;

I have a 120V flashing light which I want to activate whenever one of multiple sources sends a signal. I also want to have a small panel mount LED light signal which source the activation is coming from.

My original plan was to use a 24VDC circuit to and from each source to trigger a relay to send the 120V to the flashing light. The issue I found was that when one source sends 24VDC to the relay (also powering small panel mount LED) it will backfeed to the other panel mount LEDs.

Is this the best approach to the circuit, and if so I'm assuming diodes on each "activation" 24VDC line would solve the issue. Is there a good mounting solution to including stand alone diodes in an electrical enclosure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach, using a 24V DC relay circuit switched through diodes, is appropriate.

Mounting LED holders on the enclosure would enable point-to-point wiring of the diodes and LED current-limiting resistors to the LEDs, onward to the relay coil. The freewheeling diode for the relay coil could be located at the coil terminals.

[image]